# Setting up SAML Identity Provider with .NET Web Forms and AWS Cognito

Tags: .net, webforms, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm currently working on a project where I need to set up a SAML Identity Provider for Single Sign-On (SSO). Our existing system uses .NET web forms (C#) with ASPNETDB for authentication and membership, and it leverages a SQL database as the authentication store.

The challenge I'm facing is integrating this setup with a third-party service provider that utilizes AWS Cognito for their SSO.

Has anyone had experience with such an integration? Specifically:

1. How can I effectively bridge our .NET web forms authentication with SAML for SSO?
2. Are there any recommended libraries or tools for implementing a SAML Identity Provider in a .NET environment?
3. What are the key considerations when integrating with AWS Cognito as the service provider?

Any guidance, best practices, or code samples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I attempted to integrate our .NET web forms (C#) authentication system, which uses ASPNETDB and a SQL database, with a SAML Identity Provider for Single Sign-On (SSO). My goal was to seamlessly connect our existing membership and authentication system with a third-party service provider that employs AWS Cognito for their SSO.

**What I tried:**
I explored several libraries and tools recommended for implementing a SAML Identity Provider in a .NET environment.
I followed the integration guidelines provided by the third-party service provider and AWS Cognito documentation.

**Expected Outcome:**
I anticipated a smooth integration where users could authenticate through our .NET web forms system and gain access to the third-party service via SSO without needing to re-authenticate.

**Actual Result:**
I encountered challenges in bridging our authentication system with SAML. The integration wasn't as seamless as expected, and users faced issues during the SSO process. Additionally, there were discrepancies between the AWS Cognito documentation and the actual behavior observed.